# C input and output - can we make it adaptive?

Tags: c

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double recalc(double a);

int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("\nPlease enter a duration in ms. This program will "
           "calculate the corresponding amount of hours.\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Your input in ms is %.15f hours\n", recalc(a));
    return 0;
}

double recalc(double a)
{
    a = a/1000/60/60;
    return a;
}
```

So, this program converts ms into hours.
So far, so good.

I used %.15f to stay in reasonable dimensions here, but if I type in... let's say 0.0000000000001, my 15 decimal places are not enough. Also, but that is only cosmetics, I'd like to cut off the invalid 0s at the end if I, for example, type in 360000000. 
Anyone got a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something: What I'd really like to achieve is to have at least 10 decimal places != 0 if I input very low numbers and cut off the invalid 0s at the end should they occur.

Comment: please update your question to include specific example input and output scenarios

Comment: Please what is an "*invalid 0*"?

Comment: an invalid 0 is is a 0 that is not needed, e.g. in the number 1.1450000000.

Comment: @Jon Scott:  I did in the OP. just use 0.0000000000001 and 360000000 as input and you will see the problem, even with 15 decimal places. I think this is a very complex problem I am addressing here, but maybe someone has a rather simple solution.

Comment: @xing: yes I have, but that doesn't change anything

Comment: OT: Consider using a more meaningful name for your function, something like `hours_from_ms()`.

Comment: did you try %.15g instead of %.15f ?

Comment: Note that 0.000,000,000,000,1 milliseconds is 100 attoseconds (or 0.1 femtoseconds).  A femtosecond is one millionth of a nanosecond.  When do you have measurements that are significant at the scale?  Clearly, fixed point notation is not going work well for such tiny units, any more than working with æons (1E9 years) is going to be comfortable.  You probably need to use `%e` or perhaps `%g` notation.  If you want 'engineering notation' (exponents are a multiple of 3), you'll have to work harder.

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing the exponent and sprintf the value. Remove trailing zeros as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *recalc(double a);

int main(void)
{
    double a;
    printf("\nPlease enter a duration in ms. This program will calculate the corresponding amount of hours.\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("Your input in ms is %s hours\n", recalc(a));
    return 0;
}

char *recalc(double a)
{
    static char value[100] = "";
    char *sign = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    int exp = 10;

    a = a/1000.0/60.0/60.0;
    sprintf ( value, "%e", a);
    sign = strpbrk ( value, "-");
    if ( sign) {
        sscanf ( sign + 1, "%d", &exp);
        exp += 5;
    }
    sprintf ( value, "%.*f", exp, a);
    len = strlen ( value) - 1;
    while ( value[len] == '0') {
        value[len] = '\0';
        len--;
    }
    if ( value[len] == '.') {
        value[len] = '\0';
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... That one did it.. I don't quite understand it yet (still very new to C), but I'm gonna dig into that one :)